# Python 3.5 Auto-mouse click

Tags: python, python-3.x, controls, mouse

I need a module that can control the keyboard, mouse movement and clicks . 
I tried to use  PyUserInput and PyAutoGUI  but none work for python 3.5.
Can someone help ?

Comment: What OS are you using? GUI automation modules often are OS specific. That being said, PyAutoGUI works with Windows, Linux and mac OS.

Comment: @AlexFung I am using Windows 8 at the moment.

Comment: What exactly does "none work for Python 3.5" mean? Can you elaborate a little bit? As Alex Fung said, at least pyautogui should work.

Comment: @AlexFunt I tried installing PyAutoGUI using the "pip install pyautogui" in the console. But i got an error message informing me that i don't have the PIL module and as much as I can see  there is no PIL module that works with python 3...

Comment: @nostradamus Again when i typed "pip install PIL" I got the message : "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL ..."

Comment: Pretty sure you need to install pillow : http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/installation.html

Comment: Have you tried `pip install pillow`? PIL is deprecated and pillow is the successor. However, this should actually be installed together with pyautogui...

Comment: @AlexFung  It worked very well using Pillow. Thank you for help !

Comment: @nostradamus It worked very well using Pillow. Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html):
You will need to install pillow.

To install pillow:
Type this in your terminal

```
pip install pillow
```